# XMLHttpRequest(); doesnt work at my discord webhook

Tags: javascript, html

## Snippet

```
  <script>
    function sendMessage() {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var uname = document.getElementById("name").value;
      var mail = document.getElementById("emailAddress").value;
      var msg = document.getElementById("message").value;

      request.open("POST", "URL");

      request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

      var params = {
        username: "Support",
        embeds:[{"color": 16711680,"title":"Benutzer: " + uname, "description":"Schreibt: " + msg + " Email: " + mail, "timestamp": new Date()}],
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(params));
      request.send(JSON.stringify(params));
    }
  </script>
```

no errors and the params look correct on console output. Discord Receives nothing. Any idea?

I expect to get a embed message from the contact form of a client to his discord channel.
My form variables look good and I get the values also correctly.

## Console Output

```
{"username":"Support","content":"Schreibt: Test Email: Test@test.com","embeds":[{"color":16711680,"title":"Benutzer: Test","description":"Schreibt: Test Email: Test@test.com","timestamp":"2022-11-30T10:32:59.001Z"}]}
```

Comment: Does Discord send a response? If it does you have no means of knowing with the above

Comment: What do you mean by `discord webhook`, is it that discord is opening a URL for you? If so, I highly doubt that it'll execute JavaScript.

Comment: I found the solution i had a typo :D in my webhook URL :D